# My reactjs reduxtoolkit slice wont update state

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit, redux-thunk

Ok so I need the message redux state to receive the message from the emailChange api call.

Im new to this so keep that in mind.

This is my  function from my auth slice actions

```
export const emailChange = createAsyncThunk(
  "auth/emailChange",
  async ({ email, change }, thunkAPI) => {

      const data = await AuthService.emailChange({email, change})
      thunkAPI.dispatch(setMessage(data.message));
      console.log(data);
      return data; 
    })
```

auth slice

```
export const logout = createAsyncThunk("auth/logout", async () => {
  await AuthService.logout();
});

const initialState = user
  ? { isLoggedIn: true, user }
  : { isLoggedIn: false, user: null };

const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: "auth",
  initialState,
  extraReducers: {
    [register.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      state.isLoggedIn = false;
    },
    [register.rejected]: (state, action) => {
      state.isLoggedIn = false;
    },
    [login.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      state.isLoggedIn = true;
      state.user = action.payload.user;
    },
    [login.rejected]: (state, action) => {
      state.isLoggedIn = false;
      state.user = null;
    },
    [logout.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      state.isLoggedIn = false;
      state.user = null;
    },
  },
});

const { reducer } = authSlice;
export default reducer;
```

where i dispatched emailChange

```
 const handleSubmit = (formValue) => {
    setSuccessful(false);
    setLoading(true);
    if (change!=="email") {
    dispatch(forgottenPassword(formValue))
    .then((response) => {
        if (response.payload.status === "PENDING"){
            setSuccessful(true);
            //navigate(`/emailsent/${formValue.email}/${true}`) 
        }
            setLoading(false);
            setMessage(response.payload)
        })  
    }else if(change==="email") {
        const {email} = formValue
        const post = {change:true, email}
        dispatch(emailChange(post))
        .then((response) => {
            if (response.payload.status === "PENDING"){
                setSuccessful(true);
            } 
                setLoading(false);
                setMessage(response.payload)
                console.log(message2) //this is the message redux state
            }) 
    }       
};
```

api call

```
const emailChange = ({email, change}) => {
  return api
    .post("/auth/emailChange", {email, change})
    .then((response) => {
      return response.data;
    });
};
```

message slice

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {};

const messageSlice = createSlice({
  name: "message",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setMessage: (state, action) => {
      return { message: action.payload };
    },
    clearMessage: () => {
      return { message: "" };
    },
  },
});

const { reducer, actions } = messageSlice;

export const { setMessage, clearMessage } = actions
export default reducer;
```

Why would this code not work?

I tried and checked many different configurations.

console logs show the correct payload is being sent to message, but the state does not update

Everything is happening correctly except the message state does not update according to console log.

I'm hoping it is something obvious in this code

This function in my auth slice actions works fine

```
export const register = createAsyncThunk(
  "auth/register",
  async ({ username, email, password }, thunkAPI) => {
    try {
      const response = await AuthService.register(username, email, password);
      thunkAPI.dispatch(setMessage(response.data.message));
      return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
      const message =
        (error.response &&
          error.response.data &&
          error.response.data.message) ||
        error.message ||
        error.toString();
      thunkAPI.dispatch(setMessage(message));
      return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue();
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: Does the `setMessage` reducer function execute? Debug it

Comment: seems to in the redux devtools. showing in the list with the payload..but the state doesnt change

Comment: What console logs are you referring to? How exactly are you verifying or validating the store updates?

Comment: How did you dispatch the `emailChange` thunk? Show the code

Comment: I don't see any overt issues in the code that would ***prevent*** the redux store from updating. Think you could create a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live?

Comment: heres the repo  github.com/clz89/Redux.git

Answer (score 1):

Okay so a better way to handle this is actually in the extraReducers. Heads up I personally use the "map object" notation but you can also use the builder. [Here](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createSlice#extrareducers) are the docs for extraReducers.

** Note it's a good idea to define what your state will be initial state.
Also you are most likely **not** getting the update because you are returning. Instead **you should be assigning the state in your reducers** i.e. in the setMessage you should do this state.message = action.payload in redux toolkit it uses immer under the hood so you can mutate state it will handle it behind the scene.

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

export const emailChange = createAsyncThunk(
  "auth/emailChange",
  async ({ email, change }, thunkAPI) => {
      const data = await AuthService.emailChange({email, change})
      // No need to dispatch the thunkAPI as it will automatically look in the extra reducers.
      return data; 
    })

const initialState = {
  message: ""
};

const messageSlice = createSlice({
  name: "message",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setMessage: (state, action) => {
      state.message = action.payload;
    },
    clearMessage: () => {
      state.message = "";
    },
  },
  extraReducers: {
   [emailChange.pending]: (state, action) => {
     // Great place to set isLoading true.
   },
   [emailChange.fullfilled]: (state, action) => {
     // Heads up its atleast action.payload might want to check in debugger if you need to dig further into the object.
     state.message = action.payload;
     // Great place to set the isLoading false.
   },
   [emailChange.rejected]: (state, action) => {
     // Great place to set an error message to display to user or whatever.
     // Might set isLoading to false here.
   },
   [register.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      // Could add a string here or back in the createAsyncThunk on the return you could destructure and add a message there then do action.payload.message or whatever.
      state.message = "Login successful";
    },
 }

});

const { reducer, actions } = messageSlice;

export const { setMessage, clearMessage } = actions
export default reducer;
```

Comment: My auth slice is seperate from the message slice...i tried adding this to my auth slice, has the same affect..nothing changed.

Comment: So as a note you can have the same extraReducers in multiple slices and they will all get called so it doesn't matter if the slices are different (so in your message slice you can have a [register.fullfilled] in there then set the message). and you changed it to assigning to the state instead of returning?

Comment: updated my answer to give an example of the messages slice listening to the register asyncThunk @ChristopherZamora

Comment: i got an error "Cannot access 'emailChange' before initialization"

Comment: when i tried to put the extra reducer in the message slice... i dont know exactly what you mean by returning....sorry im newb

Comment: o you mean returning the message

Comment: Is your repo public? Also but returning I mean not using the word return i.e. return { message: ""} I mean you are just supposed to assign the state state.message = ""

Comment: Looking up the error it has something to do with circular dependency. So guessing without seeing files auth slice is importing messages slice and messages slice is importing auth slice (importing like this isn't necessary for the extraReducers to work how I described so no fear there).

Comment: Tried some things...same behavior overall....everything seems sent right but the state doesnt update.

Comment: stuff works the same as before when i switched it to your config , with no state update

Comment: Are you still getting the same error (did you resolve the Cannot access error?) Also can you double check your create store and ensure the messages reducer is included when you create the store?

Comment: i resolved the error by taking the import for message from the auth file yes. store is correct....

Comment: const reducer = {
  auth: authReducer,
  message: messageReducer
}

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: reducer,
  devTools: true,
});

Comment: test('reducers', () => {
  let state;
  state = reducers({auth:{isLoggedIn:true,user:{username:'superzam881',email:'zamc89@yahoo.com',roles:['ROLE_USER']}},message:{message:{message:''}}}, {type:'auth/emailChange/fulfilled',payload:{status:'FAILED',message:'Email is already in use!'},meta:{arg:{change:true,email:'zamc89@yahoo.com'},requestId:'xITePiMNdATOBP_BBzswA',requestStatus:'fulfilled'}});
  expect(state).toEqual({auth:{isLoggedIn:true,user:{username:'superzam881',email:'zamc89@yahoo.com',roles:['ROLE_USER']}},message:{message:'Email is already in use!'}});
});

Comment: that is the test template for jest if that is any use..

Comment: hmm would it be possible for you to get a codesandbox with it working as is, or do you have it public by chance on github? Sorry at this point I'm kind of at a loss without being able to see it.

Comment: I was able to mkae a codesandbox that replicates the error.

Comment: test login or register form for redux mesage state rendering message correctly.  UserEmaillChange form renders messages through usestate , but is setup for redux message state but doesnt work..so if fixed it would have 2 message renders.  press login then refresh to gain access to profile page with change email form

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/p/github/clz89/Redux/draft/quirky-neumann?file=/my-app/.gitignore:16,11&workspaceId=4b263879-f827-4b5c-be30-3a26dd498b66

Comment: I had to tweak the app to run without backend so its buggy....press login submit button on login form then refresh

Comment: here is the repo  https://github.com/clz89/Redux.git

Comment: solved it thanks... bad useselector args. Thanks for your help I will use what you taught me going forward

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to solve it.
ultimately changing const

```
{message2}  = useSelector((state) => state.message.message);
```

to

```
message2  = useSelector((state) => state.message.message);
```

allowed it to work.

I also put the emailchange action in its own slice and it seemed to help but not sure.